# how to get selected Item from Action Mode and Expandable List View?

Tags: android

I have an ExpandableListView, and I want to enable Action Mode when the user Long press and item. I have managed to make the action mode works, but the problems come when I am trying to know which item was selected. This is the code of my fragment, in the `onItemLongClick` function I try to select the element the user has long-pressed (I though the ExpandibleListView would do this by itself), and then in the `ActionMode.Callback` I try to get the selected element, but I always get a null. Where is the problem? How should I do this to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment{
    private ExpandableListView listViewTimeslips;
    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback(){
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                //HERE I GET A NULL
                Timeslip timeslip = (Timeslip)listViewTimeslips.getSelectedItem();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            case R.id.action_remove:
               mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
               return true;
           default:
               return false;
       }
      //MORE CODE
    };

  }
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listViewTimeslips.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(mActionMode!=null){
                return false;
            }
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
                int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

                ((ExpandableListView)parent).setSelectedChild(groupPosition, childPosition, true);
            }
            mActionMode = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally managed to get it work. What I did is add in the `onItemLongClick` method this line:

```
listViewTimeslips.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Then, on the `onActionItemClicked`, inside the `ActionMode.Callback()` :

```
int pos = listViewTimeslips.getRefreshableView().getCheckedItemPosition();
Timeslip timeslip = (Timeslip)listViewTimeslips.getItemAtPosition(pos);
```